# Some fireEvent action will not accur after building production

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I came across a strange problem that some 'fireEvent' in views will not act after my sencha application being building production. Before building, all is normal, the action will take place as expected, however, after building production, I found that the 'fireEvent' fired by 'this' is normal, but by a variable is anormal. Following is my code.

```
Ext.define('WirelessCity.view.TopMenu', {
    extend:'Ext.Toolbar',
    alias:'widget.topmenu',

    initialize: function(){
        this.callParent(arguments);
                 var topMenu = this;

        var btn = {
            xtype: 'button',
            width: 42,
            margin: '5 0 5 3',
            border: '0',
            style: 'background:url(resources/images/left_btn.png);',
            handler: this.onMarkButtonTap,   // will work
            scope: this
        };

        var search = {
            width: 46,
            margin:'3 5 0 0',
            style:'background:url(resources/images/search_btn.png);border:0;background-repeat:no-repeat;',
            initialize: function(){
                this.element.on({
                    tap: function(){
                        topMenu.fireEvent('searchCmd', topMenu);    // will not work
                    }
                });
            }   
        }

        this.add([btn,  search]);
    },

    config: {
        docked: 'top',
        //flex: 1,
        height: 38,
        padding: 0,
        margin: 0,
        border: 0,
        style: 'background:url(resources/images/top.png)'
    },

    onMarkButtonTap: function(){
        //Ext.Msg.alert('mark');
        this.fireEvent('markCmd', this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you can only pass configs when creating new components, not functions (like `initialize`). If you want to override methods like that, you must create your own class by extending another (`Ext.Button` in this case).

For your specific usage though, you can just use the `element` option when adding the listener:

```
var search = {
    width: 46,
    margin:'3 5 0 0',
    style:'background:url(resources/images/search_btn.png);border:0;background-repeat:no-repeat;',
    listeners: {
        element: 'element',
        tap: function() {
            topMenu.fireEvent('searchCmd', topMenu);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks rdougan, but using 'initialize' function also works before building production. Why?

Comment: @user1937869 because in development it should throw a warning - but for some reason it does not. I have already raised this with the other devs.